# How to copy a datatable to a list

Tags: c#, .net

I want to copy the contents of the datatable to a list

```
List<FireFighterChiefDetails> ChiefList1 = new List<FireFighterChiefDetails>();

cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from FireFighterDetails");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = Connect.getDataTable(cmd);
```

I want the contents of dt to be copied to ChiefList1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq to DataSet:

```
List<FireFighterChiefDetails> ChiefList1 =
    dt.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(r => new FireFighterChiefDetails {
          Foo = r.Field<string>("Foo"),
          Bar = r.Field<int>("Bar")
          // etc
       }).ToList();
```

Nice to read: [Queries in LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Consider also to use some (mini)ORM (like [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)) to map query results to your class automatically:

```
string sql = "select * from FireFighterDetails";
var ChiefList1 = connection.Query<FireFighterChiefDetails>(sql).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   obj.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: He wants to have a `List<FireFighterChiefDetails>`. So  adding DataRows to that list is not desired.